# do-release-upgrade: list unsupported packeges

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I'm doing `do-release-upgrade` on a 16.04 server and it says that

```
3 installed packages are no longer supported by Canonical. You can 
still get support from the community. 

3 packages are going to be removed. 153 new packages are going to be 
installed. 500 packages are going to be upgraded.
```

Is it possible to get the list of the unsupported and deleted packages before doing the upgrade?

Comment: Runt `ubuntu-support-status --show-unsupported` pay attention to the `No longer downloadable:` part... do it after `sources.list` has been changed to the new release and source cache is up to date.

Comment: It's not possible to do so before the upgrade?

Comment: I guess not, in that case it inform you about current release's situation ... you can run it before upgrade actually takes place after source have been updated.